# pyqt treeview index error removing last row

Tags: python, treeview, pyqt, delete-row, qabstractitemmodel

I have a 2 column treeView with a simple heirarchy depth of 2; root > parent > child.  I have a removeRows call in my treeView subclass that gets evaluated when the delete key is pressed.  This seems to work fine when I delete any row but the last one.

I receive an `IndexError: list index out of range`, that seems to be coming from the node class `child` method.  This seems to occur when the `self.beginRemoveRows` method is called in the model's `removeRows`.  Strangely, the order of operations appears to be reversed, or threading is somehow causing a refresh to occur before the model knows about it's recent update.

With these code snippets I was hoping someone could provide a possible explanation or some ideas of what to try next to debug this.

from the **QTreeView** subclass,

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    if event.key() == Qt.Key_Delete:
        index = self.currentIndex()
        self.model().removeRow(index.row())
    else:
        # call base class keyPressEvent
        QTreeView.keyPressEvent(self, event)
```

from the **QAbstractItemModel** subclass,

```
def index(self, row, column, parent=QModelIndex()):
    parent_node = self.getNode(parent)
    child_item = parent_node.child(row)
    if child_item:
        return self.createIndex(row, column, child_item)
    else:
        return QModelIndex()

def getNode(self, index):
    if index.isValid():
        node = index.internalPointer()
        if node:
            return node
    return self._root

def removeRows(self, position, rows, parent=QModelIndex()):

    parent_node = self.getNode(parent)
    self.beginRemoveRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1)
    parent_node.removeChild(position)
    self.endRemoveRows()
    return True
```

from the **node class**,

```
def child(self, row):
    return self._children[row]

def removeChild(self, position):

    if position < 0 or position >= len(self._children):
        return False

    child = self._children.pop(position)
    child._parent = None

    return True
```

Comment: I think i resolved this issue by clearing the selection before removing the last index.  The treeView was trying to select something else since the selected index was being deleted and it wasn't updating the rowCount before updating... I suppose this may be a bug?

Comment: How did you do it? I'm trying to do the same to no avail. If you have resolved your question you can answer with the solution and accept your own answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took me some time, but I finally found the cause of the bug: according to this [mail](https://www.mail-archive.com/pyqt@riverbankcomputing.com/msg19414.html) in the `index` method you should check if the index exists before proceeding. Annoyingly it's not written in the [method description](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractitemmodel.html#index), nor in qt4 or qt5 documentation.

The correct implementation of the `index` method should be something on the line:

```py
def index(self, row, column, parent=QModelIndex()):
    if self.hasIndex(row, column, parentIndex):
        parent_node = self.getNode(parent) 
        child_item = parent_node.child(row)
        if child_item:
            return self.createIndex(row, column, child_item)
    else:
        return QModelIndex()
```

In my application this solved the issue.

Comment: Not sure whether anyone is watching or will see this, but just wanted to post that I just found this and it saved my butt.  I had the same problem, and this solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

This alteration to the QTreeView seemed to do the trick.  Though, I'm not absolutely positive that the problem wasn't caused by something else.

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    if event.key() == Qt.Key_Delete:
        index = self.currentIndex()
        if not index.isValid(): return

        parent = index.parent()

        # adjust selection so refresh does not trigger IndexError 
        self.selectionModel().setCurrentIndex(self.indexAbove(index), QItemSelectionModel.ClearAndSelect)

        # remove selected
        self.model().removeRow(row, parent=parent)

        return

    # call base class keyPressEvent
    QTreeView.keyPressEvent(self, event)
```